# batch file set empty variable

Tags: file, batch-file, set, environment-variables

I am working with Windows XP Professional Ver. 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600

and I am searching to eliminate a variable in this manner: set /a myVar=

When I run the code below:

```
[row 00] @echo off
[row 01] setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
[row 02] set /a zVarNum_A=1
[row 03] echo [00]: !zVarNum_A!
[row 04] set z > C:\WINDOWS\system32\zCONTAINER_00.txt
[row 05] set /a zVarNum_A=
[row 06] echo [01]: !zVarNum_A!
[row 07] set z > C:\WINDOWS\system32\zCONTAINER_01.txt
[row 08] endlocal
[row 09] @echo on
```

I have these results:

-[row 06] result is: 1
-[row 07] result is: zVarNum_A=1

The desired behavior is:

-[row 06] result null
-[row 07] result null

why isn't this code working?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not asked a question, you have only made a statement that you don't understand your results. You need to explain exactly what your code is supposed to `echo` and how that differs from what it is actually `echo`ing. As it stands your question only requires one other member to 'close' vote, so I'd suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46816246/edit) with this information as soon as possible if you do not wish for that to happen. Before you submit your edit, re-read it as if you're a potential responder and make sure that it is clear and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a variable with no value, setting an empty value undefines/removes the variable from the environment.

Comment: thanks Compo for the answer but problems are:
1)the system answers, at the same code, in different manner if the value is a number or string
2)with the row: set /a zVarNum_A= , I undefines/removes the variable from the environment, but how is possible that the output is 1 or zVarNum_A=1 ?